# how do I access the specific associative array inside foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How do I access the **specific associative array inside a `foreach` loop?**
For example, I want to display the following text: "if now the 1st date means now the month of january".

Here is what I have so far:

```
$namemonth = array(
    1  => "January",
    2  => "February",
    3  => "March",
    4  => "April",
    5  => "May",
    6  => "June",
    7  => "July",
    8  => "August",
    9  => "September",
    10 => "October",
    11 => "November",
    12 => "December"
);

foreach ($namemonth as $key => $value) {
    echo "if now the $key[1] date, that's means now the month of $value[1]";
}
```

But when I try to run the code, the following value is displayed in the browser:

> **if now the date, that's means now the month of a.** until 12*

Comment: use only $key and $value instead of $key[1] $value[1]

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to pass index to display value. Simply echo `$key` and `$value` directly

```
foreach ($namemonth as $key => $value)
{echo "if now the $key date, that's means now the month of $value <br>";}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer given but which I only want to show key ($ 1) and value ($ january). Can you help me ?

Comment: So you dont need to display value from february to december?

Answer (score 0):

To give an explaination of what you are doing wrong, lets move through the code you provided:

First your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($namemonth as $key => $value)
```

- `$namemonth` is the `array`
- `$key` is the current index of the `array`, eg. `$namemonth[1], $namemonth[2], ...`
- `$value` is the value of the current `array` index

`$key[1]` translates to `1[1], 2[1], 3[1] ...`. 
`$value[1]` translates to `January[1], February[1], March[1] ...`

As you can see, the *values* you are trying to get are wrong. `1[1]` doesn't exist and neither does `January[1]`.

**If you really want only *January* to be printed, then do this:**

```
foreach ($namemonth as $key => $value)
{
    if($key == 1)
    {
        echo "if now the $key date means now the month of $value<br/>";

        // Use break to quit the foreach loop after `if` statement is true
        break;
    }
}

// Output
if now the 1 date means now the month of January
```

Comment: Thank You so much you really help full me Red, now i cant show output ;                                                                                                         **  if now the 1 date means now the month of January**

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this.

```
$month_names = array(
    1 => "January",
    2 => "February",
    3 => "March",
    4 => "April",
    5 => "May",
    6 => "June",
    7 => "July",
    8 => "August",
    9 => "September",
    10=> "October",
    11=> "November",
    12=> "December"
);
// Here $month_names is an array.
foreach($month_names AS $month_number => $month_name){
    // Here $month_number is a key of an array.
    // Here $month_name is a value of an array.
    echo "if now the $month_number date, that's means now the month of $month_name <br/>";
}
```

> OUTPUT

if now the 1 date, that's means now the month of January

if now the 2 date, that's means now the month of February

if now the 3 date, that's means now the month of March

if now the 4 date, that's means now the month of April

if now the 5 date, that's means now the month of May

if now the 6 date, that's means now the month of June

if now the 7 date, that's means now the month of July

if now the 8 date, that's means now the month of August

if now the 9 date, that's means now the month of September

if now the 10 date, that's means now the month of October

if now the 11 date, that's means now the month of November

if now the 12 date, that's means now the month of December